self inverse rational equations
This is not a "check my work" question, but I will explain some of my thoughts and ask if they are valid but lacking or entirely invalid or some third option.

I'm working on a fun little project, but I ran into a wall. I need a way to generate self inverse functions that satisfy $f(0)$ being an asymptote, and $f(1)=1$. of course $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ works but is it the only one? this is the wall. how do I break it?

I have tried setting up a system of equations to see, and it got me $f(x)=\frac{h(x)}{x*g(x)}$, where $h(1)=1,g(1)=1$ and $x=\frac{h\left(\frac{h(x)}{x*g(x)}\right)}{\frac{h(x)}{x*g(x)}*g\left(\frac{h(x)}{x*g(x)}\right)}$
rearanging the last equation gives me:$\frac{g(x)}{g\left(\frac{h(x)}{x*g(x)}\right)}=\frac{h(x)}{h\left(\frac{h(x)}{x*g(x)}\right)}$
am I correct in assuming that the only way for this to be true (assuming $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are polynomials) is for $g(x)=c*h(x)$? and if that is true then the only solution is $f(x)=\frac{h(x)}{x*c*h(x)}$, $c=1$? thereby making $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ the only self inverse rational function with an asymptote at $0$ and has $f(1)=1$? if this reasoning is correct, then what about if you don't assume $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ to be polynomials?
